# How to create a many to many self-referencing relationship cakephp

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x, self-reference

The cakephp docs state the following:

```
You can even create self-associated tables to create parent-child relationships:

class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('SubCategories', [
            'className' => 'Categories'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('ParentCategories', [
            'className' => 'Categories'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Which sounds good, but the code above doesn't actually do anything by itself. Like the code above looks like it should describe a self-referencing many to many relationship but if you take an existing Table class and just add that to the `initialize` function, nothing happens. There has to be some associated schema presumably which isn't shown.

So it's not clear how to `actually` set up a self-referencing relationship.

I've tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories_categories` (
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`,`child_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And then baked that... but it's not clear to me how to get that to actually work with models and which models to create and what associations to put in them nor how to get those to be represented by a form element.

Comment: The rest of the association definitions for such relationships work like normal `hasMany` and `belongTo` associations, hence why the docs don't go into all of those details in this particular section.

Comment: @GregSchmidt If you found the docs clear on this point then good for you but I didn't, which is why I posted this question.